# Encoded files won't open in pages?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on exporting/saving a string to a rtf file, but the file will not open in pages. The file saves and I can open it in Text Wrangler, so things are working, do any of you know why it won't open in Pages?

Code:

```
-(IBAction)saveFile{
  NSString *myString = @"Hello";
  NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
  [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"rtf"]];
  NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

  if ([panel runModal]==NSOKButton) {
       BOOL saveResults = [myString writeToURL:[panel URL] 
                               atomically:YES
                               encoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding
                               error: nil];
  }
  }
```

I tried different encoding, NSUTF8..., NSUTF16..., NSASCII... no change.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Giving a file a `.rtf` extension doesn't actually make it an RTF. You're just writing plain text to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the code seems to just write the string "Hello" to the file. That's not how rtf files work. You need to save the file in rtf format, which is not the same as just plain text. [This page](http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html) shows an example of an rtf document.

So instead of outputting just "Hello" to the file, try outputting:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
Hello\line
}
```

And that will open in Pages.

Comment: I did not know that - thanks. Do you know of any good resources for rtf files?

Comment: @littleDrummerBoy Well it depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to output the text yourself, then just take a look at that page to get a general idea of how rtf works. You can also create an attributed string (a string that lets you choose which parts are bold or italic and so on), and convert it into an rtf file. You can also read in rtf files into attributed strings. Take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html).

Comment: @Hassan- Thanks. We have a specific file format we use at work, I'm wanting to read the file, then convert it to rtf. I have the reading part, just working on saving as rtf. Thanks for the links, they look like they'll fill in the blanks.